# how to remove character escaping from a string in C#

Tags: c#, sql, string, escaping

I have some code that takes input from and excel spreadsheet and imports it into a SQL Server database. I am having some trouble dealing with strings that have double quotes in them. 
Here is what happens:
A cell has this text in it -> pipe 3/8"

When I bring that text into the C# string object, the value looks like this: pipe 3/8\"

So, when I attempt to query SQL, to look for this item, it searches for 3/8\" which id does not find.

How can I output the string from the C# string object so that it does not have the escape characters in it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the value looks like this: pipe 3/8\"

But only in the debugger. Show it somewhere and the \ will be gone.

Comment: Oh, I see. You are correct the query actually contained double quotes, like it should but here is the kicker...the item in the database had two single quotes to indicate inches, instead of a double quote. That's why it wasn't being returned in the result of the query. Looks like I have some data clean up to do. Thanks very much for your super-fast response!

Answer (score 1):

In SQL your string should be 3/8" again. The escape character \ will only exist while the string is loaded in C#.

Comment: Thank you for your response. See above.